# TextClock highlighting the day for no reason

Tags: javascript, android

I'm displaying the date as a 24 hour format like this:

`string name="date_format">EEEE, d  MMMM</string`

When I run the app, for a couple of seconds, it is working normally, but after the `EEEE` is showing as if it is misspelled.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnsc6.png -image of the bug. It is Thursday in Portuguese.

I also want to know how to add text to the `date_format` string, like "de" between "d" and "MMMM" because when I add "de" to the string, it shows the date day and "e".